# How to inactivate a strip in Python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, effects

After I make a cross effect strip, this new strip is now referenced in:
`bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip`
Then I try to make a new cross fade transition elsewhere by first setting .select as False in all sequences and then selecting two strips and adding the cross effect strip. Now I get the wrong results apparently because of the active strip. How do I inactivate the active strip?

Comment: By wrong effect do you mean the transition is backwards? are the selected strips in the right order for start to end. Check the order in `bpy.context.selected_sequences` - to get no active strip try `bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip = None`

Answer (score 1):

I deselect all strips successfully via:

```
for s in bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all:
    s.select = False
```